# How could I add a controller in MVC 5 visual studio 2013 ultimate?

Tags: controller, visual-studio-2013, resharper

[image]

Is the "add controller" option gone? I updated my visual studio to the latest version. When I right click on the controllers folder, this is the screenshot. What's going on? Any fix? The template is MVC project I am pretty sure.

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed? Have you modified the right click context menus in any way?

Comment: Resharper installed. I uninstalled resharper and reininstalled vs. Everything is fixed now. Thank you.

Comment: Great, glad I was able to help you out.

Comment: have you reinstalled Resharper?

Comment: No. I did not reinstall resharper after that. You have to uninstall resharper and reinstall vs. Reinstall vs with resharper installed cannot solve the problem!

Comment: that's impossible... doesn't exist any documented case of this scenario, I have VS2013 Ultimate installed with Resharper8, and I am not alone :)

Comment: well. I only did it once. I'm just telling you what I did and it is solved now. I will send you a screenshot when I get a chance

Comment: I do not want to be right, but you see the effects, you do not see the cause; good luck

Comment: What do you think the cause of it then?

Comment: Its really hard to understand the problem, my conclusion is that your solution has been created before update, so in your project definition you have a wrong ProjectTypeGuid, check my last answer update, I hope you solve your problem

Comment: I created this project after update and I updated all dependencies from Nuget packager.  I checked projectTypeGuid, it has that long line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to reinstall your `VS`. How you can read from [**release notes**](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/release-notes), in the final release there are 2 different way to add an `mvc controller` in `VS2013`:

1. **Right Click on the "Controllers" folder in your MVC project**
2. **Add > Controller**
3. **Choose a Controller Template.**

[image: add controller]

Otherwise you can:

1. **Right Click on the "Controllers" folder in your MVC project**
2. **Add > New Scaffolded Item**
3. **Choose a Controller Template**

[image: add scaffold]

**EDIT**

**Resharper** can't be the cause of problem, doesn't exist any documented case of that problem with **Resharper**; sure **Resharper** have **Hide overridden Visual Studio menu items**, but the only options to hide can be:

> 1. Extract Method Refactoring
> 2. Rename Refactoring
> 3. Encapsulate Field Refactoring
> 4. Extract Interface Refactoring
> 5. Remove Parameters Refactoring
> 6. Reorder Parameters Refactoring

There is not any documented case of scenario, try yourself at [youtrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP?q=hide%20menu%20item%20controller)

You can say **TFS** is the problem, then **Resharper** is the problem, then **Outlook** is the problem... but the only problem can be your Visual Studion installation and update

**EDIT**

My conclusions: I think you have created your project before last update, so there isn't an easy way to change the type of a project in Visual Studio project once it is created.

Open in a text editor your `.proj` file and find `ProjectTypeGuids` element,  every `GUID` inside its a project type `GUID`([source](http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs)), find that:
Have something like this?

> {F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325}

or this?

> {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}

change to this:

> {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}

Comment: I reinstalled the VS and tried both way. No success. Cant find any controller templates.

Comment: what do you mean tfs is the cause of your problem? have you a local tfs server on your machine?

Comment: I'm wrong. It was the resharper causing the problem.